# doctrine Discriminator Column update

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, query-cache

I have a problem on update DiscriminatorColumn name

Entities:

```
/**
 *@ORM\Entity
 *@ORM\Table(name="item")
 *@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 *@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="item_type", type="string")
 */
abstract class Item
{

}


/**
 *@ORM\Entity
 *@ORM\Table(name="product")
 *@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
abstract class Product extends Item
{

}

/**
 *@ORM\Entity
 *@ORM\Table(name="vehicle")
 *@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
abstract class Vehicle extends ItemBundle\Product
{

}


/**
 *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Aussiito\Bundles\VehicleBundle\Entity\Repository\CarRepository")
 *@ORM\Table(name="car")
 */
class Car extends Vehicle
{
}


class CarRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getListCars(){
        return $this->findAll();

    }
}
```

Before I didn't add the annotation: @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="item_type", type="string") on "Item", So by default I had the column dType. I wanted to rename the fields by " item_type " so I added the annotation And I execute the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```

The modifcation on the database was executed successfully but When I call the function getListCars(), I have the following error:

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t3.id AS id_4, t3.created_at AS created_at_5, t3.updated_at AS updated_at_6, t2.id AS id_7, t1.id AS id_8, t0.id AS id_9, t3.dtype FROM car t0 INNER JOIN vehicle t1 ON t0.id = t1.id INNER JOIN product t2 ON t0.id = t2.id INNER JOIN item t3 ON t0.id = t3.id':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't3.dtype' in 'field list'

So I thought it was the cache and I executed the following commands:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result  
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

But I have the same error.

Anyone have the solution ?